# Error in data statement in Fortran

Tags: fortran, syntax-error

Part of a code in a Fortran project that I am trying to compile is

```
  implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
  dimension fact(1:5)
  data fact / 
  d660p=rpt1*dp(6,beta2,rpt1)*d3(0,6,0,beta2,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
 1     +rpt2*dp(6,beta2,rpt2)*d3(6,0,0,beta2,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
  d606p=rpt1*dp(6,beta2,rpt1)*d3(0,0,6,beta2,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
 1     +rpt3*dp(6,beta2,rpt3)*d3(6,0,0,beta2,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
  d066p=rpt2*dp(6,beta2,rpt2)*d3(0,0,6,beta2,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
 1     +rpt3*dp(6,beta2,rpt3)*d3(0,6,0,beta2,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
  d633p=rpt1*dp(6,beta3,rpt1)*d3(0,3,3,beta3,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
 1     +rpt2*dp(3,beta3,rpt2)*d3(6,0,3,beta3,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
 1     +rpt3*dp(3,beta3,rpt3)*d3(6,3,0,beta3,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
  d363p=rpt1*dp(3,beta3,rpt1)*d3(0,6,3,beta3,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
 1     +rpt2*dp(6,beta3,rpt2)*d3(3,0,3,beta3,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
 1     +rpt3*dp(3,beta3,rpt3)*d3(3,6,0,beta3,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
  d336p=rpt1*dp(3,beta3,rpt1)*d3(0,3,6,beta3,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
 1     +rpt2*dp(3,beta3,rpt2)*d3(3,0,6,beta3,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
 1     +rpt3*dp(6,beta3,rpt3)*d3(3,3,0,beta3,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)/
```

however, compiling generates the following errors

```
mc.f(2003): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...

  data fact /
------------------^

mc.f(2018): error #5082: Syntax error, found END-OF-STATEMENT when expecting one of: ( <IDENTIFIER> <CHAR_CON_KIND_PARAM> <CHAR_NAM_KIND_PARAM> <CHARACTER_CONSTANT> <INTEGER_CONSTANT> ...
 1     +rpt3*dp(8,beta8,rpt3)*d3(0,6,0,beta8,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3) /
------------------------------------------------------------------^
compilation aborted for mc.f (code 1)
```

Does anybody knows how to get the code working?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error you get is because `data fact /` is on a line on its own with nothing after the opening slash. The compiler expects a constant or parameter name and tells you so. As is, the `data` statement is incomplete. (Thanks for High Performance Mark for pointing this out. I missed this in my earlier answer.)

You can make the compiler treat whole `data` statement up to the closing slash as a single line by using the continuation mark on every line after the `data` line. Your continuations continue only the expressions inside the data. (And the items inside `data`should be separated by commas.)

Fixing the continuation and the commas will not make the code compile, though.

The `data` statement initialises variables when the program starts. The numbers between the slashes must therefore be constants or named `parameters`. You cannot use expressions, not even expressions on constants. (The expression `3*0.0` has a special meaning inside `data`; it means three times the value zero, i.e. `0.0, 0.0, 0.0`.)

If you want to initialise your array, use assignments, which will calculate the entries based on the current value of the variables:

```
  fact(1) = rpt1*dp(6,beta2,rpt1)*d3(0,6,0,beta2,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
 1        + rpt2*dp(6,beta2,rpt2)*d3(6,0,0,beta2,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
```

or, if you also need the intermediary variables:

```
  d660p = rpt1*dp(6,beta2,rpt1)*d3(0,6,0,beta2,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)
 1        + rpt2*dp(6,beta2,rpt2)*d3(6,0,0,beta2,rpt1,rpt2,rpt3)

  fact(1) = d660p
```

By the way, your array has five entries, but you are trying to initialise six. And `implicit` variable naming isn't a good idea either.

Comment: No probably - implicit variable typing  is simply not a good idea (except for implicit none)

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Thanks. I really didn't pay much attantion to the spotty continuation marks. I've added your explanation.